# Get product of each pair in an array

Tags: arrays, product

I have an array of integers and I have to find product of each pair in array.
Say array is `{1,2,3,4}` then output should be `{1*2, 1*3, 1*4, 2*3, 2*4, 3*4}`.

Is there any way other than brute force one to get above result. By brute force I mean take one number from array and loop through the array and store product of each pair. Can this be done in time better than `O(n^2)`?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions, your question aims at a more general topic. Your question is probably better suited at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If there is no redundancy, there is no other way than executing `n*(n-1)/2` multiplications.

Imagine a graph where each item is a node and each edge represents the multiplication of the nodes is connecting.

That results into a *complete graph* and your output is the result of each edge and you will have `n*(n-1)/2` of those.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Since you could have O(n^2) unique results you need O(n^2) operations to access each of these numbers.

For example, take the case where all numbers in the 2 arrays are unique primal numbers.